# PHP filter_input_array with FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING allows empty string

Tags: php

I'm using the `filter_input_array` function to clean `$_POST` vars submitted from an HTML form.

The problem is that in certain cases I am using the `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` flag and it allows an empty string i.e. `$value = ''`, but if that form field was left empty, in some cases, it needs to be left as `NULL`.

The problem occurs when the database query fails due to a foreign key check failing, this happens because the field was submitted as an empty string instead of `NULL`.

So before I go out rewriting a tonne of queries to make an empty-string check, could anyone tell me how I can configure this `filter_input_array` input array so that this input string is sanitized and yet either some text value or `NULL`, but not `''`.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this rule apply to all empty strings or only some? If it's everything, you can simply do something like `$_POST = array_map(function($v){ return $v === '' ? null : $v; }, $_POST);` to change them. If it's a custom rule for some fields, you'll need to define those somewhere yourself

Comment: If a form field was empty, such as `<input value="">` usually is, then naturally an empty will appear in `$_POST`. That's not really `filter_*` injecting it. You'd have to convert empty strings into NULL yourself anyway.

Comment: @scrowler unfortunately it's only for certain fields which are foreign keys since there are other fields which should allow empty strings, hence I'm wondering if there is a filter flag for this case.

Comment: @mario yes, but I'd still rather not do it manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom filter:

```
$filter = array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => function ($input) {
  $filtered = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  return $filtered ? $filtered: null;
});
```

And then use it in `$args`:

```
$args = array(
  'value' => $filter
);

$inputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
```

Comment: That's great! Care explaining the FILTER_CALLBACK-I'm guessing it's a constant for doing exactly this - creating custom filters? –

Comment: It's a filter type like `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php It accepts a callback function in `options`. You can do anything in that callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the built-in flags called `FILTER_FLAG_EMPTY_STRING_NULL`. This will replace empty strings with `NULL`.